# Pagecontrol dots are not changing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to work with a `page control`. This is what I did. I've added one onto my view in the `storyboard`.

Then in my `ViewDidLoad`

```
   images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.jpg"], nil];
    pagecontrol = [[UIPageControl alloc]init];
    self.imageIndex = 0;
    [pagecontrol setNumberOfPages:images.count];
    [pagecontrol setCurrentPage:imageIndex];
```

Like you can see I have an array of four images. I've added a pagecontrol onto an imageview.  I also added two swipe gestures onto the imageView (Left and right). What I want to do now is that when I swipe:

- The image is changed
- The dot is updated with the correct position in the array

This is my code for right swipe:

```
- (void)next:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if(imageIndex == images.count-1){
        imageIndex = images.count-1;
    }else{
        imageIndex++;
    }
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.imgGallery
                      duration:1.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        self.imgGallery.image = [images objectAtIndex:imageIndex];

                    } completion:nil];
    [pagecontrol setCurrentPage:imageIndex];
}
```

**Problem**

My images are changing properly. But my pagecontrol dot is not updating and also it is showing only 3 dots.

Can anybody help ?

Comment: set current page value as 3 or 4 (other than 0) and check on loading the pagecontrol,whether the dot is placed correctly or not @Stef Geelen

Answer (score 1):

1. enable paging in scrollview

[self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

2. Set delegate to your scrollview

Comment: I don't have a scrollview? should it always be in combination with a scrollview ?

Answer (score 0):

where You define A pageControll

```
 [_tutorialPageControll addTarget:self action:@selector(changPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
_tutorialPageControll.currentPage = 0;
    _tutorialPageControll.numberOfPages = TutorialArray.count;
```

and in where You want a Chang thepage

```
_tutorialPageControll.currentPage = imageIndex;
```